# MySQL Order By Sum of Subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select a group of rows from table and order by a group of subqueries:

```
SELECT *, 
(SELECT Count(id) > 0 FROM places_users WHERE places_id = places.id) AS verified_bool,
(SELECT Count(id) > 0 FROM places_services WHERE places_id = places.id) AS services_bool
FROM places
ORDER BY sum(verified_bool + services_bool) DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

But it only returns 1 result. The subqueries check other tables that are connected to the original row. I only need to verify that those other tables have at least 1 result so I am using a boolean and then attempting to sum up the subqueries 0's or 1's and arrange the original results from those with the greatest sum to those with the least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the sum in the order by clause:

```
SELECT *, 
(SELECT Count(id) > 0 FROM places_users WHERE places_id = places.id) AS verified_bool,
(SELECT Count(id) > 0 FROM places_services WHERE places_id = places.id) AS services_bool
FROM places
ORDER BY (verified_bool + services_bool) DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```